# Simple Prolog implement about multi-agent argumentation

Tags: prolog, multi-agent

New to logic programming (Prolog). Come across a simple question but dont know how to code it in prolog.

Question is like you have several arguements: argument(a),argument(b)..., and several attack relations like attack(a,b) which means argument a attacks argument b. So given an argument I want to find out if it is a grounded one. "Grounded" for an argument a means if b attacks a, then there exists another argument, say c attacks b. If no argument attacks c then we say a and c are grounded.

Can you give an example how to implement this grounded/1 program to achieve this goal.

Not sure I make it clear....But welcome to give any advice (or code)!!

Comment: in your example (b attacks a, c attacks b) all three are grounded ? What if you also have d attacks c, which of them would be grounded ?

Comment: Example (b attacks a, c attacks b) gives a,c are grounded, b isn't. If d attacks c then a and d are grounded. c is no longer grounded because it is attacked by d and no argument protects c by attacking d.

Comment: But in that last case (where d attacks b), shouldn't b be also grounded ? Because b is protected by d also...

Comment: In my last comment I meant "where d attacks c"

Comment: sorry i made a mistake. So if c attacks b, b attacks a, then c,a are grounded. If d attacks c, c attacks b, b attacks a, then d,b are grounded. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Basically you can start off by the one that no one attacks is the first grounded argument. And then find the one, say b, that the first grounded attacks, clearly b is not grounded. The one that attacked by b is grounded because it is protected by the first grounded argument. Further grounded ones can be found this way. Besides if x attacks y, and y attacks x then none is grounded. Hope i made it clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I've understand from your explanation, an argument is grounded when there are no other grounded arguments attacking it.

You can define a procedure `grounded/1` which obeys this rule straightforward in prolog:

```
grounded(A):-
  argument(A),    % A is an argument
  \+              % for which there does not exist
  (
    attack(B, A), % an attacker
    grounded(B)   % which is grounded
  ).
```

[Edit after comment by OP]:
If you have to deal with cycles, then you will probably need to keep a list of visited "attacks", no forbid cycles:

```
grounded(A):-
  grounded(A, []).


grounded(A, L):-
  argument(A),
  \+
  (
    attack(B, A),
    \+ member(B, L),  % Here we forbid cycles
    grounded(B, [A|L])  % We add the current argument to the list of forbidden arguments
  ).
```

Comment: I found a bug: if a relation like argument a and b attack each other, then the program will loop forever. How to fix this?

Comment: @user16125: If you need to deal with cycles you will probably need to keep track of the attacks (see edited answer)

Comment: Depending of the cycle, the grounded semantics may be the empty set, leading the argumentation to different view points, or formally preferred extensions. It could be a good exercise finding out all preferred extensions, when the grounded semantics is empty.

Comment: @gusbro, consider my answer about the argument grounded semantics, as a guide for the prolog equivalent answer. It should be reformulated, there are more considerations to know. Maybe you are right or there's something missing yet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to write in Prolog but the grounded semantics are computed starting from  arguments that weren't attacked, given the argument tree.

(Hope it guides [@gusbro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/463243/gusbro) to find a proper answer to this thread.)

To explain how it's computed, I'll introduce the following function *F(x) = {x defends y}*, where:

- [image]
- [image]
- If one defended argument is attacked by other deffended argument, then the attacked argument will be removed from the set.
- And so on, until the function cannot be more extended with more arguments, which it reached the minimal fix point in *F*.

**(Exemple 1)** given the following argumentation graph, the grounded extension is *Eg = {c, e, f, a}*.

[image]

So, the first function begins with:

[image]

Now let consider computing of grounded extension with cycles.

**(Example 2)** In the given argumentation graph bellow, *e* defends *b* and *d*, but *b* is attacked by *d*, then it can't be included in the grounded semantics. From this point we have a conflict-free set *{e, d}*. From *{e, d}* we can apply agin the function *F({e, d}) = {e, d, a}*, where *d* defends *a* from *b*. Applying again the function *F({e, d, a}) = {e, d, a}*, showing that *{e, d, a}* is the minimal fix point in *F*. Therefore, {e, d, a} is the grounded extension.

[image]

**(Example 3)** In the argumentation tree below, the grounded extension [image], since There aren't arguments that weren't attacked. Otherwise, If the argument e did not attack itself, the grounded extension should be [image], which is not the case.

[image]

In this last example, the cycle rises to different preferred extensions, where you can use as support the equivalent concept of argument labeling defined elsewhere by Martin Caminada.